# Custom View namespace issue

Tags: android, android-custom-view, attr

I tried several ways to resolve it but nothing works.

First of all i added  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.devmob.mediaequalizer"` to my parent node in xml. but nothing works when i press **Ctrl+Space** And then i find that if app is targeting greater than 17 just add `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to parent node.

**CustomView**

```
public PotentiometerView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        initialize();
    }

    public PotentiometerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset)
    {
        super(context, attributeset);

        //get the attributes specified in attrs.xml using the name we included
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeset,
            R.styleable.Potentiometer, 0, 0);

        try 
        {
            //get the text and colors specified using the names in attrs.xml
            isEnable = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.Potentiometer_Potentiometer_enable, true);

            max = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Potentiometer_Potentiometer_max, 100);//0 is default

            int progresss = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Potentiometer_Potentiometer_progress, 0);

            setProgress(progresss);

        }
        finally 
        {
            a.recycle();
        }

        initialize();
    }

    public PotentiometerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset, int i)
    {
        super(context, attributeset, i);

        initialize();
    }
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="Potentiometer">
         <attr name="Potentiometer_max" format="integer" />

         <attr name="Potentiometer_progress" format="integer" />

            <attr name="Potentiometer_enable" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resource>
```

Is there any work around to resolve this issue. My customView attributes are not showing in xml.

Comment: some times this happens but don't worry its IDE problem many times (try restarting in case) but it will work in runtime

Comment: I have tried restarting eclipse , so i can add attribute by pasting in xml like Potentiometer_progress="40"